# how to display programming code as colorful and correctly formatted in flutter

Tags: flutter, gist, code-view

I want to display the [content](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Untrusted-Game/8eb08d9de68baab0f97d9015611efecd/raw/da8e5b49b512b9825318b3dccaa071624121cf0c/untrusted-lvl6-solution.js) of this url in flutter application with code viewer, is that possible to do that? I am not talking about only dart code.

I tried to show it with flutter_markdown, and I think it is basic

Comment: maybe this can help https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_syntax_view

Answer (score 2):

you can use syntax_highlighter package.

```
dependencies:
  syntax_highlighter: ^1.0.0

import 'package:syntax_highlighter/syntax_highlighter.dart';
```

To display a block of code, use SyntaxHighlighter widget. You can specify the language of the code using the language parameter, and the actual code to be displayed using the text parameter. like example:

```
SyntaxHighlighter(
  language: 'dart',
  text: '''
void main() {
  print('Hello!');
}
''',
)
```

Comment: Actually, it is very old package, thanks for the recommendation